# Robocopy with spaces and dashes

Tags: robocopy

I'm having trouble with my robocopy. For some reason, it cannot read the source and destination locations correctly. I want to copy everything from GIS_Testing into an existing folder called GIS_Testing_Backup.

```
robocopy "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\GIS_Testing\" "C:\Users\xxx\OneDrive - University of XX\GIS_Testing_Backup\" /mir
```

I'm not sure if I need the last backslash on either the source of destination. It appears that the quotes and the dash in the .bat file aren't being interpreted properly. Anybody know how to fix this so it's read correctly? This is how the .bat file is being read in the command prompt:

```
  Started : Friday, February 16, 2018 9:48:31 AM
   Source - C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\GIS_Testing" C:\Users\xxx\OneDrive\
     Dest -

    Files :
  Options : /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /R:1000000 /W:30

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

ERROR : Invalid Parameter #2 : "-"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. I got rid of the trailing backslashes and removed quotes on the source file since it didn't have any spaces in it anyway.

Result:

```
robocopy C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\GIS_Testing "C:\Users\xxx\OneDrive - University of XX\GIS_Testing_Backup" /mir
```